# Navigator.push not working in Flutter in this code

Tags: flutter, dart

Navigator.push not working in Flutter in this code.
Main Function is that when text&image upload proceess is end, go to homepage.
Actually, upload Process are working...

```
 Future _uploadFile(BuildContext context) async {
      if (_image != null) {

      final firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child('post')
          .child('${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.png');

      final task = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(
        _image,
        StorageMetadata(contentType: 'image/png'),
      );

      final storageTaskSnapshot = await task.onComplete;

      final downloadUrl = await storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

      await Firestore.instance.collection('post').add(
          {
            'contents': textEditingController.text,
            'displayName': widget.user.displayName,
            'email': widget.user.email,
            'photoUrl': downloadUrl,
            'userPhotoUrl': widget.user.photoUrl,
          });
    } else {
      await Firestore.instance.collection('post').add({
        'contents': textEditingController.text,
        'displayName': widget.user.displayName,
        'email': widget.user.email,
        'photoUrl': 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/woonsancommunity2-c95f8.appspot.com/o/post%2FNo%20IMG.001.png?alt=media&token=47a39955-39a0-447f-8846-d89149f40ee3',
        'userPhotoUrl': widget.user.photoUrl,
      });
    } 
    Navigator.push(
      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context) => HomePage(widget.user)),
    );
  }
```

Comment: not working in what sense? Are you getting any error log?

Comment: also, you could simply your code.